# Trying to launch photoshop with scripting

Tags: asp-classic, photoshop

Im trying to launch photoshop in my windows server using asp coding but its 2 days now the only I can read in my browser is **Server.CreateObject Failed** lol

Using this: Set PhotoshopApp = Server.CreateObject("Photoshop.Application")

It looks like its the correct call, I guess there is something that must be set in the server.

Could someone give me some lights?

Comment: I've never done this, but this might be helpful:  http://www.virtualsecrets.com/adobe-photoshop-jsx-web-server.html

Comment: Thank you so much, but Im affraid it cant work with my server since the example mentions a much older windows version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photoshop is a desktop app it has not been written to be launched this way.

But you can use other COM objects to launch it in the desktop:

http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-execute-a-dos-command/batch-file/exe-from-asp.html

But I have from personal experience WScript.Shell seems not to work in newer IIS versions.

If you have access to SQL:

[How can I run sqlcmd.exe from an ASP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587189/how-can-i-run-sqlcmd-exe-from-an-asp-page)

If you can register a COM:

http://www.shotdev.com/asp/asp-run-execute-exe/asp-execute-exe-wscript-shell/

I have used the last two methods in the past.

EDIT: Based on your comment replies ASP JPEG can do everything you need:

http://www.aspjpeg.com/manual_04.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However both scripts open the file in the background, not in the foreground eg, on the taskbar. So the program I made cannot edit my images.

Comment: What do you want to do to the images? There are quite a few graphic COM programs that might be able to do what you are trying to do in photoshop.

Comment: Ok here is the scenario:


A) There is always an image on the server, lets call it Image1.tga


B) A user uploads his image through a webpage, lets call it Image2.tga


C) Photoshop opens both images.


D) Editing begins:


1) Activates the Alpha channel at Image2
2) Ctrl+A at Image2
3) Ctrl+C
4) At Image 1, creates an Alpha channel
5) Ctrl+V on Image1 Alpha Channel
6) Save as the Image1 as new tga file


Seems easy task, but which other program could do that in a server, and also be triggered by asp code?
Thank you!

Comment: Ok understand and got you covered, check out ASPJpeg it, can do all of that and more:

    http://www.aspjpeg.com/manual_04.html

Comment: Sorry over 5 mins edit:

Ok understand and got you covered, check out ASPJpeg it, can do all of that and more:

http://www.aspjpeg.com/manual_04.html

Quite sure it can't handle TGA images, but JPG, GIF and PNG are covered. You could also do what you are wanting in the HTML5 canvas if your users are using modern browsers again without TGA.

Comment: Before try this component, I tried to do the same work with png's (in photoshop), but it seems I cant have the same result as I did with tga's.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You shouldn't have any problem with alpha channels on 24bit PNG.

Comment: What Im trying to do is exactly what I described with the scenario above. Im so sorry, I cant explain it better.